# How to enumerate all possible combinations of elements

Tags: perl, combinations

I want to enumerate all possible combinations of elements array. For example: I have array:

```
$r = ('a1','a2','a3' ...).
```

I want to print all combinations of element arrays:
a1a2, a1a3, a1a2a3, etc .
where
a1a2 != a2a1, a1a2a3 != a1a3a2 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that there's [a module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aCombinatorics) for that:

```
use Math::Combinatorics;

@r = qw(a1 a2 a3 ...);
#@all_combinations_of_r = map { combine($_,@r) } 1..@r;
@all_permutations_of_r = map { permute(@$_) } map { combine($_,@r) } 1..@r;
```

Comment: From the example it rather look that `permute` would be more suitable. Last item shows that order or items is significant.